# WPF stop click event on MainWindow if backgroundworker on page1 is true

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, backgroundworker

WPF vb.net desktop app.

I have a simple layout for testing. A `MainWindow, btnMain, frame1, page1` and `btnPage1.`

If `btnPage1` click event is busy with a `background worker` (which is downloading something), what is the best way to stop the user from clicking `btnMain` on `Main Window` until background worker is finish from page 1 ?

ADD* : Could I use NavigationService.Navigating Event to warn user before backgroundworker is false(done) ? How would I?

Comment: Disable btnMain and enable it back when backgroundworker completes it's task

Comment: I was thinking lost focus event on download button, but that button is hidden while backgroundworker is true. I do have a cancel button while backgroundworker is true. I can try that. Yet, I just didn't know what the best option for this is?

Comment: @BenjaminJones Why do you need to do it when focus is lost?  On the click of `btnPage1` disable `btnMain`, when the BGW completed event is fired enable `btnMain`.  That's it.

Comment: Well if the button responsible for download triggering is hidden user cannot click it either. It's your choice - to hide or to disable. Though I think disabling of a button less confusing for a user - he will still know that download is possible, but not right now

Comment: @Blablablaster. This would work, but how about if I have 100 buttons on MainWindow. I won't but my point is, this would not be the best solution if I did.

Comment: NavigationService.Navigating Event would not be an option?

Comment: @BenjaminJones It's simple enough to programmatically disable all buttons, or even the entire form.  Just traverse the entire control tree disabling all buttons.

Comment: Could I use NavigationService.Navigating Event to warn user before backgroundworker is false(done) ? How would I?

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one control you need disabling then wrap all the controls on the page in a [BusyIndicator](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator).

It's part of the WPF Toolkit and you use it like this:

```
<xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}" >
        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource SampleContent}"/>
</xctk:BusyIndicator>
```

This will disable all the content inside it while `IsBusy` (a property on the view model) is true.

So set this to `true` when you start your download and reset it to `false` on the download completed event.

The control has a `BusyContent` property you can use to show a custom message. You can even customise the contents of the message to show the downloading progress:

[image: Busy indicator variants]